# How to check if a function throws an error or not in Chai

Tags: javascript, testing, exception, chai

I am having a test in which I am calling an API which I expect to throw an exception. I want to check whether the API call throws an exception or not. If yes, pass the test if not then fail the test.
here is my test:

```
  it("expecting API to throw an error",async () =>{
    const contractResponse = await axios.get("API endpoint");
  })
```

I have tested it with `expect.fail()` and `expect(async ()=>{...}).to.throw()` but both of these fails the test. I want to pass the test when the API throws an exception. How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried including `await` -> `await expect(async() =>{...}).to.throw()` ?

Comment: @JeffreyRam I tried your method but this too doesn't work. I have written it like this:
```
await expect(async()=>awiat axios.get("API endpoint")).to-throw();
```